# Get Outer Html of a Click event of a Class and Check Where Another div with Specific Exists or Not

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, loops

**Code In Loop:**

```
<div id="ActualDiv@(t)" class="MemberActualDiv">
     <select name="MemberCountType@(t)" id="@("MemberCountType" + t)" class="MemberCountType form-control ">
      <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="<">Less Than (&le;)</option>
      <option value=">">Greater Than (&ge;)</option>
      <option value="=">Equal</option>
     </select>
     <select name="MemberCount@(t)" id="@("MemberCount" + t)" class="MemberCount form-control ">
       <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="8">7 Or More Than 7</option>
     </select>
     <button id="@("AddMore" + t)" class="AddMoreButton AddMoreButton0 btn btn-blue" type="button">Add More +</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".AddMoreButton").click(function () {

        //Check If Existing is being Added
        var classname = $(this).attr("id");//.html();
        var id1 = classname.replace("AddMore", "");
        alert(classname);
        classname = $('#AddMore' + id1).outerHTML();
        alert(classname);
});
```

**Dynamic Code Added Using Javascript**

```
<div id="MemberDescriptionAdd1" class="MemberDescriptionAdd1" style="display:none;">
                    <select name="MemberCountTypeX" id="MemberCountTypeX" class="MemberCountTypeX form-control ">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Condition</option>
                        <option value="<">Less Than (&le;)</option>
                        <option value=">">Greater Than (&ge;)</option>
                        <option value="=">Equal</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="MemberCountX" id="MemberCountX" class="MemberCountX form-control ">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Members</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="8">7 Or More Than 7</option>
                    </select>
                    <button id="RemoveX" class="RemoveButtonX btn btn-blue" type="button">Remove</button>
                </div>
```

**Actual View**
[image]

What Actually Happening Is On `AddMore` Button i want to added the Dynamic Div with incremental Id and Remove the Div on Remove Click

So What I'm trying to do is get the outer div of the button click `AddMore` and then will try to find class/id if exists.

If there is any other better Id I'm open to them as well

**Dynamic Adding Jquery:**

```
//Inside the Above Jquery Itself
var adddiv = $('#MemberCountDiv');
        alert(adddiv.html());
        var value = "MemberDescriptionAdd" + id;
        adddiv.find('.MemberDescriptionAdd').attr('id', value);
        adddiv.find('.MemberDescriptionAdd').attr('class', value);
        alert(adddiv.html());
        var divname = $('#ActualDiv' + id).append(adddiv.html());
```

Comment: Can you post? How you are generating dynamic HTML?

Comment: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: outerHtml()  is not a function in jquery .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: @Satpal added the code

Comment: @DhavalPatel the example that you have provided, will it work with dynamic id as they are not assigning ids, if not then we need to access the same in the controller as well

Comment: Is there any reason that on `$( document ).load()` you couldn't run a `foreach()` on existing markup to find how many elements exist and set an incremental variable that would track your progress via a global JS variable, and send that to the script that generates new code?